# Does the same file take up room on the server when merged to a branch in subversion

Tags: svn

Lets presume I am on a subversion branch, and merge changes from trunk. It applies 20 Mb of changes to my branch, from the changes on trunk. Lets presume also these files were not ever modified by me on my branch, so are identical to trunk.

Then I commit by branch and I see it sending up the changes to the subversion server (I use TortoiseSVN)

Will this add 20Mb of data to the server on my branch, or will the server detect that the new files that I am committing are the same files as on trunk and just keep a reference on my branch to the files on trunk, thus preserving the disk space on the server?

Comment: AFAIK it should _not_ add the files a second time, unless they were modified. Even then only the delta should be added, unless the files were marked as binary. But you can easily test that out yourself: create a fresh repository, import a few _big_ files into a "trunk", create a "branch" and start copying. What size do you get for the repository after such steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion doesn't ever duplicate data when you do `svn copy` in the repo.  But in other cases (like in your question here) if you commit identical file content multiple times it may duplicate the data in the repository.  The answer depends on if the repository supports representation sharing.

1.6.0 added representation sharing to the FSFS file system.  As long as the repository is FSFS format 4 (see first line of the `db/format` file under your repository) and the Subversion server is at least version 1.6.0 then it can support representation sharing.  However, representation sharing can be disabled (it's on by default) in the `db/fsfs.conf` file.  See the `enable-rep-sharing` option under the `[rep-sharing]` section of that configuration file.

With representation sharing Subversion tracks a map of the hash of file content to the representation that we use to store the data in the repository.  During commit the content is checked to see if a matching hash already exists in the repository, in which case that existing representation is used.  If not then a new representation is created and added to the map.  You'll find this map in a SQLite database file at `db/rep-cache.db` under your repository.

In order to avoid storing data again rep-sharing needs to have been enabled when the previous copy of the same data was committed, otherwise it won't be in the rep-cache.db.  So if you have an old repository that was upgraded, the answer may also depend on if the commit of the previous data exists in the rep-cache.db.

If you want to be sure that everything is in the rep-cache.db the best way is to do a dump/load cycle with Subversion 1.6.0 or newer.